# How can this function pointer not point to a function?

Tags: c++

Why is the pointer function `*pFcn` not pointing to an address? It points to `Add`, which isn't `&Add`. nor does it return an address. Why is that?

```
int Add(int nX, int nY)
{
    return nX + nY;
}

int main()
{
    // Create a function pointer and make it point to the Add function
    int (*pFcn)(int, int) = Add;
    cout << pFcn(5, 3) << endl; // add 5 + 3

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "It points to Add which isnt &Add" -- it is, a function name is implicitly convertible to a function pointer.

Answer (score 4):

If `foo` is a function, then (except in some specific cases*) both `foo` and `&foo` express a pointer to the function: Functions immediately decay to pointers to themselves, so `foo(x)`, `(*foo)(x)` and `(**foo)(x)` are all the same.

---

When given a choice, prefer passing functions by reference rather than by value, though:

```
template <typename R, typename ...Args> R invoke(R (*f)(Args...), Args... args)
{
    return f(args...);

    // bad: "&f" is not useful
}
invoke_p(add, 1, 2);
```

```
template <typename R, typename ...Args> R invoke_r(R (&f)(Args...), Args... args)
{
    return f(args...);

    // good: "&f" is the expected function pointer
}
invoke_r(add, 1, 2);
```

---

<sub>*) For example, `sizeof(foo)` and `sizeof(&foo)` are not the same; the former isn't legal.</sub>

Comment: I +1ed anyway, but the first sentence isn't quite correct: `foo` does not denote a pointer to a function (as your examples show).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Yeah, I wasn't too happy with it, either. Better now?

Comment: The first sentence is almost right, that is, until a language lawyer comes along... functions don't *always* decay to pointers although there are very few cases where they don't. You can try getting a reference to a function and a reference to a pointer to the same function to see a case where the function does not decay. For a less complex example, the address of operator applied to the function and applied to a pointer would not be the same. `&f` is valid where `&*f` is not.

Answer (score 0):

`printf("%p\t%p",pFcn,Add)`

pFcn gives the address of the function which it is pointing which in this case is the address of funciton Add. pFcn(1,2) calls the function.